# MS Access Query Input must contain at least one table or query

Tags: sql, ms-access

need assistance in running the below part of the code

```
        db.Execute "ALTER TABLE QA09_Adj ADD COLUMN EV_DebCred text;"
        Dim debCred As String

        For nId = 1 To rows
          strSQL = "SELECT Debito_Credito_1 FROM QA09_Adj WHERE Id = "
          Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL & nId)
          debCred = rs!Debito_Credito_1
          rs.Close
          Set rs = Nothing
          If debCred = "C" Then
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO QA09_Adj (EV_DebCred) VALUES ('D') WHERE Id = "
            Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL & nId)
            qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
          Else
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO QA09_Adj (EV_DebCred) VALUES ('C') WHERE Id = "
            Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL & nId)
            qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
          End If
        Next nId
End Sub
```

Tried a couple of variations without success. Debug shows error the mentioned error on **qdf.Execute dbFailOnError**

Thanks!

Comment: INSERT with a WHERE clause does not make sense. Maybe you want to update the table?

Comment: you're so right, tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, since tables in `SELECT` and `INSERT` are the same, likely you want to run `UPDATE` with `IIF` conditional logic. However, since you are using QueryDefs, consider proper parameterization and not concatenation:

```vb
' PREPARED STATEMENT
strSQL = "PARAMETERS [paramId] LONG;" _
          & " UPDATE QA09_Adj q" _
          & " SET q.EV_DebCred = IIF(q.Debito_Credito_1 = 'C', 'D', 'C')" _
          & " WHERE Id = [paramId];"

Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)      ' INITIALIZE QUERYDEF

For nId = 1 To rows  
  qdf!paramId = nId                          ' BIND PARAMETER
  qdf.Execute dbFailOnError                  ' EXECUTE ACTION
Next nId

Set qdf = Nothing                            ' RELEASE RESOURCE
```

Of course. if *rows* includes all rows of data, then no loop or parameter or even QueryDef is needed:

```vb
db.Execute "UPDATE QA09_Adj q SET q.EV_DebCred = IIF(q.Debito_Credito_1 = 'C', 'D', 'C')", dbFailOnError
```